Run traefik with subdomains behind a reverse proxy
Following setup:
I have an reverse proxy which is exposed to the internet (Nginx proxy manager) all the traffic is first coming to this proxy. Then I want to redirect specific domains to another reverse proxy (trafik) which then automatically creates routes for running docker services in the network. I´m having trouble setting up trafik the right way I think. I also want only subdomains of a specific domain to be redirected to the reverse proxy.

Nginx proxy manager config.
I can see from the logs that the redirect to traefik is working

My traefik setup looks like following



3. This is my service I want to access via wildcard

The question is now, what am I missing in order to work? If I want to access my whoami.*.de domain I get a gateway timeout


The problem of is pretty simple. The traefik container and the whoami container must be in the same network in order to work.
